# How to set the lower and upper bounds of a single variable in a single equation in gams

Tags: gams-math

Is this possible?:

```
boundary_of_x..
   19.0 =l= x =g= 22.1;
```

where x is a positive variable and boundary_of_x is an equation. Or do I have to do this in two equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in one equation, you need two, or (better) use the `.lo` and `.up` attribute of the variable:

```
x.lo = 19.0; x.up = 22.1;
```